# how convert an ics file (exported from google calendar) as textual diary

Tags: conversion, calendar, google

I'd like export (possibly automatically) from google calendar an .ics file and convert it to a text diary (maybe .md, or .html).
A way there is, with the IFTTT scripts, but is too commercial, I am searching for a open source solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there's any pre-baked solution, but if you know a bit of Python you can try [ics.py](https://icspy.readthedocs.io/en). Just `pip install ics` then:

```py
from ics import Calendar

md_template = """
### {start}
*{name}*: {desc}""" 

with open("basic.ics") as f:
   cal = Calendar(f.read())

print("## Calendar")
for e in sorted(cal.events):
    print(md_template.format(start=e.begin.humanize(), name=e.name,
                             desc=e.description))
```

Comment: I get this error: "ImportError: cannot import name Calendar"

Comment: What's your Python file called? Make sure _it_ isn't called `ics.py` too

Comment: In effect (how can youi know?): "python convert-ics-to-diary.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert-ics-to-diary.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ics import Calendar
  File "/mnt/dati/schede/desktop/ics.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ics import Calendar, Event
ImportError: cannot import name Calendar"                  I see a **new file** ics.pyc, with a _wrong ecoding_

Comment: erm you should probably remove all `.pyc` files and try again. If a Python file has the same name as a module it's importing, it will try to import itself

Comment: Now I get this error: "File "/home/duns/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/arrow/parser.py", line 119, in parse_iso
    return self._parse_multiformat(string, formats)
  File "/home/duns/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/arrow/parser.py", line 283, in _parse_multiformat
    raise ParserError('Could not match input to any of {0} on \'{1}\''.format(formats, string))
arrow.parser.ParserError: Could not match input to any of [u'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'] on '20181119T084520Z''

Comment: Looks like a date parsing problem. Works fine on [this public Google calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics).  
Personally, I'd opt Python3 if you can (`pip3 install ics` and `python3 foo.py`).
Also, check the [ics.py docs](https://icspy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4/)

Comment: Thank you: it worked!! But so I get a terminal output, how can get a (md) file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86013/discussion-between-duns-and-declension).